# Why is the jQuery countdown not working with the documented code?

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am using this [jQuery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) here and it seems pretty straightforward but i must be missing something. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var austDay = new Date();
    console.log(austDay.getFullYear() + 1);

    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
    $('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay, format: 'dHMS'});
});

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Here is the [page](http://k-kouture.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration was kind of messy. You configured the countdown plugin twice (in `effect-ini.js` and in a `<script>` tag in your HTML page). Also, you had syntax errors in your effect-ini.js.

1. Remove the contents of your `<script>` tag in your index page (the one that starts with `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">`
2. Replace your effect-ini.js with this: http://pastebin.com/ULtGSAUt

And it should work.

Comment: what was the syntax error and how did u figure it out so i can learn in the future...and thanks again

Comment: @John IIRC you were using `$(function()` instead of `function()`